# Display tiltle in img.show

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I need to display the title of an image when it is opening in a new window using `Image.show()`. But the title displaying is some random text.

Discovered the solution of the problem using cv2. But I need a solution in PIL.

```
img = Image.open("picture.jpg")
Image._showxv(img, title='Result')
```

I expect the output to display the title of the image when it is showing. But getting some random text now.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Windows 10

Comment: Do you know of, or have, a command-line tool in Windows that can display images with a title? IrfanView? ImageMagick's `display` maybe? Something from Microsoft? If so, you could save your image to a temporary place and then shell out to one of those tools like in `src/PIL/ImageShow.py` at line 112

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not aware of that. Actually "Image._showxv(img, title='Result')" is taking an argument of title. But its still not getting displayed when it runs.